# Smooth ParametricPlot3D with RegionFunction?

Tags: plotting, regions

What's the preferred way to paint spots on a curved surface without getting raggedy edges? Using ParametricPlot3D with RegionFunction gets the shape I want but increasing PlotPoints slows things down considerably. Counterintuitively Reducing PlotPoints to 50 gives better looking results than 100:

```
With[{a = 0.8, b = 0.4, r = 5^0.5, l = 10, points = 50}, 
 ParametricPlot3D[{{x, -Sqrt[r^2 - x^2], z}, {x, Sqrt[r^2 - x^2], 
    z}}, {x, -r, r}, {z, -l/2, l/2}, 
  RegionFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, z}, (x/a)^2 + (z/b)^2 < 1 && y > 0], Mesh -> None, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotPoints -> points]]
```

First image has points =50, second image has points = 100.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The problem is that you're asking Mathematica to draw a very large plot and then throw away most of it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSbcF.png Why not reduce the range of `x` and `z`? With `ParametricPlot3D[..., {x, -a, a}, {z, -b, b}, ...]` I get a very nice plot.

Comment: `MaxRecursion` is more important here, set `MaxRecursion -> 10`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's the preferred way to paint spots on a curved surface without getting raggedy edges?

I use [`MeshFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html), [`MeshShading`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshShading.html), and [`Mesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html):

```
Show[
 (* Head *)
 ParametricPlot3D[
  (1 + 0.05 Cos[u]) {Sin[u] Cos[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], 0} + {0, 0, 1.05 Cos[u]},
  {u, 0, π}, {v, 0, 2 π},
  (* mouth *)
  MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, x + 0.5 (2 y^2 - 2 (z + 0.5))^2]},
  MeshShading -> {Black, Lighter@Red, Yellow},
  Mesh -> {{-0.85, -0.82}},
  (*****)
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, PlotPoints -> 100],
 (* Eyes *)
 ParametricPlot3D[
  Sin[1.9 (u - 0.45)]^2 (0.36 + 0.8 (Sqrt[0.5 + 2 Abs[v]])) Cos[1.5 v] *
     {-Sin[u] Cos[v], -Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[u]},
  {u, π/6, π/2}, {v, -π/6, π/6},
  (* pupil & iris *)
  MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, 
     Sin[1.9 (u - 0.49)]^2 (0.36 + 0.8 (Sqrt[0.5 + 2 Abs[v]])) Cos[1.5 v]]},
  MeshShading -> {White, Lighter@Blue, Black},
  Mesh -> {{1.06, 1.077}},
  (*****)
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, PlotPoints -> 100],
 (* Tongue *)
 ParametricPlot3D[
  {-u, 0, -u^2/4 - 0.15} + 0.15 Sqrt[Sqrt[(1.2 - u)]] *
     (2 Cos[v] {0, 1, 0} + Sin[v] {-u/2, 0, 1 - 0.5 Sin[v]}/Sqrt[u^2 + 1]),
  {u, 0.5, 1.2}, {v, 0, 2 π}, PlotStyle -> Red, Mesh -> None],
 PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It has the advantage of having borders that meet each other exactly.  (Pasting a surface patch on another surface usually requires a small gap between them, or rounding error in the GPU causes the image to shimmer.)

Comment: +1 seems insufficient...beautiful use of  mesh functions and mesh shading...

Comment: @"Michael E2" Nice. MeshFunctions makes more sense here than RegionFunction as I expect it defines the boundary before constructing the shape so probably reduces the calculation.  I wish I had got to this before Halloween, the possibilities are endless :o)  Also the comment about having the borders meet each other exactly is huge. I had needed to include a small gap just for that reason before. Your post should be part of the manual!

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this can achieve the desired outcome (or at least a starting point):

```
r = ImplicitRegion[
  x^2 + y^2 == 5 && (x/0.8)^2 + (z/0.4)^2 < 1, {{x, -5, 5}, {y, 0, 
    5}, {z, -5, 5}}]
dr = DiscretizeRegion[r, MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> Red, 2 -> Red}, 
   Background -> Black];
rp = RegionPlot3D[dr, Background -> Black];
Row[{dr, rp}]
```

[image]

Comment: nice solution, with lots of new lessons in it for me! I found however that I was able to make the shapes smooth after searching more in stackexchange and coming across suggestions to use ContourPlot3D instead of ParametricPlot3D. This worked really well, but I'm glad I got your reply first as it illustrates some new techniques for me.

Comment: @DrBubbles glad you found what you needed :). MMA is very flexible and I learn a lot from the creativity of this community.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution using ContourPlot3D:

```
With[{a = 0.8, b = 0.4, r = 5^0.5, l = 10}, 
 ContourPlot3D[
  x^2/r^2 + y^2/r^2 == 1, {x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r}, {z, -l/2, l/2}, 
  RegionFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, z}, (x/a)^2 + (z/b)^2 < 1 && y > 0], Mesh -> None, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  PlotRange -> {{-.9, .9}, {2, 2.5}, {-0.5, 0.5}}, PlotPoints -> 60]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
With[{a = 0.8, b = 0.4, r = 5^0.5, l = 10, points = 75}, 
 ParametricPlot3D[{{0, r, 0}, {x, Sqrt[r^2 - x^2], z}},
  {x, -r, r}, {z, -l/2, l/2}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, s, t}, (x/a)^2 + (z/b)^2]}, 
  Mesh -> {{1}}, MeshShading -> {Automatic, None}, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotPoints -> points, 
  PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]