# Transform a RegionFunction in ContourPlot3D

Tags: plotting, regions, geometric-transform

This is related to a [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129272/smooth-parametricplot3d-with-regionfunction) but now I would like to apply a geometric transformation to the region function first. (I am trying to paint a spot on a cylinder, where the spot is the region that intersects a transformed hyperboloid):

```
r = 5; l = 10;
tube = Show[{With[{a = 0.5, b = 0.5, c = 50},
 ParametricPlot3D[
  RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}}][{a (1 + u^2)^0.5 Cos[
      v], b (1 + u^2)^0.5 Sin[v], c u}], {v, 0, 2 Pi}, {u, 0, 
   1.0}, Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> {{-r, r}, {-r, r}, {0, l}}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, (x^2 + y^2) < r^2]
  , PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", MaxRecursion -> 5]]
}];
Show[Graphics3D[ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[\[Theta]], r Sin[\[Theta]], z }, {\[Theta], 0, 
 2 \[Pi]}, {z, 0, l},
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.2], Mesh -> None][[1]],Boxed -> False], tube, Axes -> True]
```

Gives the cylinder and hyperboloid expected, showing the intersection surface I want to draw:

[image]

But this:

```
With[{r = 5, l = 10, a = 0.5, b = 0.5, c = 50}, 
ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 == r^2, {x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r}, {z, 0, l}, 
RegionFunction -> 
RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}}] Function[{x, y, 
  z}, (x/a)^2 + (y/b)^2 - (z/c)^2 == 1], Mesh -> None,
PlotRange -> {{-r, r}, {-r, r}, {0, l}}, BoundaryStyle -> None,
Boxed -> False, Mesh -> None, Axes -> True, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.2]]]
```

Gives the complete cylinder, not the transformed region I tried to define:

[image]

I was hoping to get something more like this, i.e. the part of the cylinder bounded by the intersection with the tilted hyperboloid:

[image]

That used a similar syntax but without the GeometricTransformation:

```
With[{a = 0.5, b = 0.5, r = 5, l = 5}, 
ContourPlot3D[x^2/r^2 + y^2/r^2 == 1,
{x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r}, {z, -l/2, l/2}, 
RegionFunction ->
Function[{x, y, z}, (x/a)^2 + (z/b)^2 < r^2 && y > 0], Mesh -> None,
PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
PlotRange -> {{-r, r}, {-r, r}, {-l, l}}, PlotPoints -> 10]]
```

How do I apply the geometric transformation to the region function? Or should I be doing it some other way?

Comment: Have you tried `RegionIntersection`?

Comment: Ah, that looks like a new function to me since i looked last, maybe just what I need! Will have a go with that. Thanks

Comment: RegionIntersection  appears to need correctly specified regions, while my cylinder and hyperboloid don't appear to be regions, rather they are Graphics3D.  I expect there's a solution using MeshRegion as @"Michael E2" used in the previous  question (linked at the top) but I can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the function you're looking for is `TransformedRegion`. (And a dash of code voodoo -- it seems like there are a hundred ways in which this *could* be done, but this is the only one I found that actually worked.) In your case, it works like

```
treg = TransformedRegion[
 ImplicitRegion[(x/a)^2 + (y/b)^2 <= 1 + (z/c)^2, {{x, -r - 1, r + 1}, 
  {y, -r - 1, r + 1}, {z, 0, l}}], 
 RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}}]
]
```

This gives you a valid region, which (unfortunately) you can't use directly in `RegionFunction` because `RegionFunction` needs to return `True` or `False` for any given arguments. So to use this region for plotting (in `RegionFunction` or in `RegionPlot3D`) you need to use

```
Evaluate@RegionMember[treg]
```

Plotting the two regions of interest:

```
With[{a = 0.5, b = 0.5, r = 5, l = 10, c = 50},
 Show[
  ContourPlot3D[
   x^2/r^2 + y^2/r^2 == 1, {x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r}, {z, 0, l},
   Mesh -> None, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
   PlotRange -> {{-r - 1, r + 1}, {-r - 1, r + 1}, {0, l}}, 
   PlotPoints -> 10, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5]],
  RegionPlot3D[
   Evaluate@
    RegionMember[
     TransformedRegion[
      ImplicitRegion[(x/a)^2 + (y/b)^2 <= 
        1 + (z/c)^2, {{x, -r - 1, r + 1}, {y, -r - 1, r + 1}, {z, 0, l}}], 
         RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}}]], {x, y, z}], 
      {x, -r - 1, r + 1}, {y, -r - 1, r + 1}, {z, 0, l}, 
   PlotPoints -> 20],
  ViewPoint -> {Pi, Pi/2, 2}
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

And to paint the spot on the cylinder:

```
With[{a = 0.5, b = 0.5, r = 5, l = 10, c = 50},
 Show[
  ContourPlot3D[
   x^2/r^2 + y^2/r^2 == 1, {x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r}, {z, 0, l},
   Mesh -> None, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
   PlotRange -> {{-r - 1, r + 1}, {-r - 1, r + 1}, {0, l}}, 
   PlotPoints -> 10, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5]],
  ContourPlot3D[
   x^2/r^2 + y^2/r^2 == 1, {x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r}, {z, 0, l},
   RegionFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y, z}, 
     Evaluate@
      RegionMember[
       TransformedRegion[
        ImplicitRegion[(x/a)^2 + (y/b)^2 <= 
          1 + (z/c)^2, {{x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r}, {z, 0, l}}], 
        RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}}]], {x, y, z}]],
   Mesh -> None, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
   PlotRange -> {{-r, r}, {-r, r}, {0, l}}, PlotPoints -> 10],
  ViewPoint -> {Pi, Pi/2, 2}
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

In general, if you're working with regions a lot, I would recommend sticking with equations and inequalities and using `Reduce` to manipulate them. In your scenario, I found that `RegionIntersection` gave me very little that I could actually work with. That could well be problems with how I was using it, and there might be a way to get it to work. But I've found that, while occasionally useful, the `Region` functionality can be pretty limited when it comes to manipulating regions in certain situations. (Not that you were using the `Region` functionality -- this is a critique of my earlier comment, not the approach you used in your question.)

Comment: I would certainly not have stumbled across that!
    Evaluate@RegionMember[TransformedRegion[ImplicitRegion[      I agree,  Region has its uses but is a bit limited. Yours is a very effective and adaptable solution. Much appreciated!

Comment: @DrBubbles Glad you liked it. It was an interesting (if a little frustrating) problem.