# Transform a RegionFunction in ContourPlot3D problem

Tags: plotting, regions, geometric-transform

The (inspired) solution by @aardvark2012 to this original question:
[Transform a RegionFunction in ContourPlot3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/153983/transform-a-regionfunction-in-contourplot3d)  worked well until an update appears to have changed the expected behavior (some time since ~2017):

If you specify PlotPoints -> 10 you still get the expected result:

[image]

If you specify PlotPoints -> 25 you get the unexpected result:
[image]

**How do we get just the spot on the cylinder?**

Although the original solution used PlotPoints -> 10, I have many similar constructions which previously give the expected result but now do not, so at that point @aardvark2012's solution was a general solution.

Here's @aardvark2012's solution from the above post: if you change  PlotPoints -> 10 to PlotPoints -> 25  you get the unexpected result above.  I needed to increase PlotPoints as the outline for other similar constructions was too coarse.

```
With[{a = 0.5, b = 0.5, r = 5, l = 10, c = 50}, 
  Show[
    ContourPlot3D[
      x^2/r^2 + y^2/r^2 == 1, {x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r}, {z, 0, l}, 
      Mesh -> None, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotRange -> {{-r - 1, r + 1}, {-r - 1, r + 1}, {0, l}}, 
        PlotPoints -> 10, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5]], 

    ContourPlot3D[
      x^2/r^2 + y^2/r^2 == 1, {x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r}, {z, 0, l}, 
      RegionFunction -> 
        Function[{x, y, z}, 
          Evaluate@
            RegionMember[
            TransformedRegion[
              ImplicitRegion[(x/a)^2 + (y/b)^2 <= 1 + (z/c)^2, {{x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r}, {z, 0, l}}], 
                RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}}]], {x, y, z}]], 
      Mesh -> None, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
      PlotRange -> {{-r, r}, {-r, r}, {0, l}}, PlotPoints -> 10], 

    ViewPoint -> {Pi, Pi/2, 2}]
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `RegionBoundaryStyle -> None`.

```
With[{a = 0.5, b = 0.5, r = 5, l = 10, c = 50}, 
 Show[ContourPlot3D[
   x^2/r^2 + y^2/r^2 == 1, {x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r}, {z, 0, l}, 
   Mesh -> None, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
   PlotRange -> {{-r - 1, r + 1}, {-r - 1, r + 1}, {0, l}}, 
   PlotPoints -> 25, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5]], 
  ContourPlot3D[
   x^2/r^2 + y^2/r^2 == 1, {x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r}, {z, 0, l}, 
   RegionFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y, z}, 
     Evaluate@
      RegionMember[
       TransformedRegion[
        ImplicitRegion[(x/a)^2 + (y/b)^2 <= 
          1 + (z/c)^2, {{x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r}, {z, 0, l}}], 
        RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}}]], {x, y, z}]], 
   Mesh -> None, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
   PlotRange -> {{-r, r}, {-r, r}, {0, l}}, PlotPoints -> 25, 
   RegionBoundaryStyle -> None], ViewPoint -> {Pi, Pi/2, 2}]]
```

[image]

- Another way is using `MeshFunction`.

```
With[{a = 0.5, b = 0.5, r = 5, l = 10, c = 50}, 
 ContourPlot3D[
  x^2/r^2 + y^2/r^2 == 1, {x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r}, {z, 0, l}, 
  Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshShading -> {Blue, Automatic}, 
  ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5], 
  MeshFunctions -> 
   Function[{x, y, z}, 
    Evaluate[(x/a)^2 + (y/b)^2 - (1 + (z/c)^2) /. 
      Thread[{x, y, z} -> {x, y, z} . 
         RotationMatrix[{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}}]]]], PlotPoints -> 50, 
  MaxRecursion -> 4, MeshStyle -> Yellow, 
  PlotRange -> {{-r - 1, r + 1}, {-r - 1, r + 1}, {0, l}}, 
  ViewPoint -> {Pi, Pi/2, 2}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution incorporating the MeshFunction into the ContourPlot3D rather than using two instances of ConcoutPlot3D. Much appreciated.